# gson de-serialization to string in java

Tags: java, android, serialization, gson

In my project I'm using gson. I have a problem when I want to de-serialize a json sub object form my class to a String
for example

```
Class X
{
    Object1 x1 // expected json -> '{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
    Object2 x2 //expected json -> '{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
    String x3 //expected json ->'{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
}
```

Gson can't de-serialize x3 since it's contents is json object but I need it as a string and not as a Java object.    Class X
    {
        Object1 x1 // expected json -> '{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
        Object2 x2 //expected json -> '{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
        String x3 //expected json ->'{"param1": "pvalue", "param2":"pvalue"}'
    }
How do I save the contents of x3 in a String and not as a object.
Thanks

Comment: what string-value are you expecting in s3?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register a custom TypeAdapter for the String and fix it.

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new MyTypeAdapter());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
....
```

[Javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)
[User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you be more specific on how do do this, please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine. Not really sure if that's the Json structure your are trying to parse though.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Response response = gson.fromJson( THE_JSON, Response.class );

        System.out.println( response.object1 );
        System.out.println( response.object1 );
        System.out.println( response.stringx );
    }

    class Response
    {
        @SerializedName("Objectx1")
        Objectx object1;

        @SerializedName("Objectx2")
        Objectx object2;

        @SerializedName("Stringx")
        String stringx;

        class Objectx
        {
            @SerializedName("param1")
            String param1;

            @SerializedName("param2")
            String param2;
        }
    }
}
```

And THE_JSON is:

```
{
    "Objectx1": {
        "param1": "value1",
        "param2": "value2"
    },
    "Objectx2": {
        "param1": "value3",
        "param2": "value4"
    },
    "Stringx": '{
        "param3": "value3",
        "param4": "value4"
    }'
}
```

Note the single quoutes around the Stringx value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply byt I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT
E/AndroidRuntime( 2705):        at com.google.myjson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:174). The problem is in the Stringx variable, I can't pars it to a String I just can't understand why if the content of a string is a Json object, it cant be serialized to string.I might have a older version of the library